# How to filter a character followed by numbers string pattern in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, like

Back in SQL Server, I use the command below to get the matching string pattern of `#1234` from the column called `Number`

```
SELECT [m].[Number]
FROM [Boats] AS [m]
WHERE [m].[Number] LIKE N'[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Now in Postgres, I have tried using the command below, but no luck:

```
SELECT m.Number
FROM Boats AS m
WHERE m.Number ILIKE '#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Any idea what pattern expression should I use to get the correct filter?

Comment: LIKE doesn't support regular expressions in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the operator `~` that uses the full power of [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

```sql
select *
from (values ('#1234'), ('#3333'), ('#abcd')) as boats (number)
where number ~* '#\d{4}'
```

A stricter version of the regex would be `'^#\d{4}$'`, so that it matches only strings that start with `#` then have 4, and only 4 numbers, and then there is the end of the string.